# Single sign on for Joomla admin and frontend

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to implement single signon for Joomla 1.5 backend and frontend. I find it kind of redundant that when the admin for instance is logged in at the backend and needs to do some user function on the frontend has to login again. Is there a way of implementing a single signon?

Answer (score 3):

Joomla! is implemented as two separate applications the front-end initiated from `/index.php` and the back-end administration from `/administrator/index.php` as such they have separate user sessions and states.

The separation is a standard security approach, while you could write your own mod_login to do this I wouldn't advise it unless you're very clear on what you're doing.

Having said that, there are 255 Joomla! extensions in the [Access & Security](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/) ——> [Site Access](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access) section dealing with logins. Have you tried looking there?

Answer (score 0):

This joomla extension can do that.
http://www.everlive.net/joomla-extensions/15-joomla-admin-from-frontend.html

Just login to frontend as an admin user. You will be logged-in automatically to backend. Further it gives you useful direct links for various backend operations like article add, edit, publish, unpublish etc. Same kind of links are available for modules and menu items.