# User logs into frontend - plugin to automatically be logged into backend

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I need to create a system plugin (no auth plugin!) where a user which logges  into the frontend automaticaly gets logged in the backend too. 
(The user has the rights to log into the backend via /administrator.)

I try to do it via the very basic code you see below, the result is positive, but if i go to the backend the user still needs to log in.

In the session table the backend session row is set, but the "guest" field is set to 1 instead of 0 and the userid is set to 0 instead of the correct id.

How can this be done?

```
function onAfterInitialise() {

if(JFactory::getUser()->get('id')) {  // logged in? 

    $credentials = array();
    $credentials['username'] = "walter"; // hardcoded first
    $credentials['password'] = "123"; // hardcoded first

    $options = array();
    $options['action'] = 'core.login.admin'; 
    $result = $app->login($credentials, $options);  // this seams to work
    if (!($result instanceof Exception)) {
        $app->redirect("www.bummer.de");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from this being a very bad idea, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750402/single-sign-on-for-joomla-admin-and-frontend/10750779#10750779) Joomla! is implemented as two applications a front-end (`/index.php`) and back-end application (`/administrator/index.php`).

In the code provided you don't show where `$app` is initialised so I'm guessing that it's probably something like `$app->JFactory::getApplication('site');`.

To login to the admin app you need to get it rather than the front-end client app e.g.

```
$adminApp->JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
$result = $adminApp->login($credentials, $options);
```

**n.b. this is untested code just typed in to stack overflow... it should be right.**

Comment: I already testet with the JFactory::getApplication('administrator') call. still no backend session created.